# how do i create a .exe file out of a WindowsFormsControlLibrary

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have created a `WindowsFormsConrtolLibrary` in `Visual Studio Code` and now I want to have it as a `.exe` file or as a type of file I can run it with.

I tried to search in my `bin\debug` folder but there is only a `.dll` file and a `.pdb` file.

Comment: Look in Visual Studio, you can create a _Windows Form Desktop Application_.  Complete the wizard then add a reference to your library

Comment: where do i have to look to create a Windows Form Desktop Application?

Comment: @BNG.exe create a new project under visual c# there's a option to choose Windows Form Desktop Application(framework or core)

Comment: Do you mean Windows Forms-App (.NET Framework)?